# issues with serialize and unserialize in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to Serialize following array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => ./assets/user_1/images/15_3_1_5__69689_zoom.jpg
        [1] => ./assets/user_1/images/15_3_1_5__69689_zoom.jpg
        [2] => ./assets/user_1/images/15_adriano.jpg
        [3] => ./assets/user_1/images/20_index.jpg
        [4] => ./assets/user_1/images/20_index.jpg
        [5] => ./assets/user_1/images/20_mag.jpg
        [6] => ./assets/user_1/images/20_images.jpg
        [7] => ./assets/user_1/images/20_images.jpg
    )
```

Serialize String is:

```
a:9:{i:0;s:47:"./assets/user_1/images/15_3_1_5__69689_zoom.jpg";i:1;s:47:"./assets/user_1/images/15_3_1_5__69689_zoom.jpg";i:2;s:37:"./assets/user_1/images/15_adriano.jpg";i:3;s:37:"./assets/user_1/images/20_contact.jpg";i:4;s:38:"./assets/user_1/images/20_About_Us.png";i:5;s:36:"./assets/user_1/images/20_photos.jpg";i:6;s:35:"./assets/user_1/images/20_index.jpg";i:7;s:33:"./assets/user_1/images/20_mag.jpg";i:8;s:36:"./assets/user_1/images/20_images.jpg";}
```

When I want to unserialize its give me in error

> unserialize(): Error at offset 9 of 300 bytes

Please help me

Comment: Serialized string is not well formatted or just a `typo`?

Comment: Post your code where you have tried it? Your controller perhaps?

Comment: I don't get notices: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ead16c4eeb1795959fa39ad89b5ec1906ce1cdc

Comment: do you store it somewhere between serialize and unserialize? Maybe it gets truncated/changed in a database.

Comment: for storing etc. you should use json_encode/json_decode. I even had problems with serialized data between different hosts ..